# javascript/jQuery Array concatenation?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some simple jQuery code:

```
var response = Array()
$('.task-list').each(function() {
  response.concat(response,$('#' + this.id).sortable('toArray'));
}
);
console.log(response);
```

The problem I'm having is that I think I'm using concat improperly- the result is an empty array. When I use array push, it works correctly.

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish.   Are you trying to add elements to a jQuery object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to set `response` to the newly formed array, as described in the specification. You currently don't use the return value at all.

The specification says that for `.concat`, the array is not altered, but the new array is returned:

> When the concat method is called with zero or more arguments item1, item2, etc., it **returns an array** containing the array elements of the object followed by the array elements of each argument in order.

Compare with `.push`, which says the current array *is* altered, and that something else is returned instead (the new length):

> The arguments are **appended** to the end of **the array**, in the order in which they appear. The **new length** of the array is **returned** as the result of the call.

So:

```
response = response.concat($('#' + this.id).sortable('toArray'));
```

Answer (score 3):

Concat returns the concatenated array, you want this instead

```
response = response.concat($('#' + this.id).sortable('toArray'));
```

Simple example

```
var a = [1,2]; 
var b = [3,4]; 

a = a.concat( b ); // result is [1,2,3,4] which is correct
```

If you do the following

```
a = a.concat( a , b ); // result is [1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4] not what you want.
```